# Bootstrap Drop Down Problems

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey im trying to implement bootstrap drop down in a text navbar here http://22twenty.com/V2
The drop down is not “dropping” as it should

id also like to have the underline not go under the caret just not sure how to stop it.

i hope someone can help

Thanks

Denver

Comment: This question does not show any code, is not constructive, will not help anyone (too localized), and is most likely to be closed. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) Try to be more issue-specific, some code would be great.

Comment: For starters, you have content before your doctype and script tags outside the body tag: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F22twenty.com%2FV2%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 Relevant to your problem: You included the dropdown script *before* loading jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the order of those line:

```
<script src="js/dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the jquery file should load before bootstrap javascript files.

Comment: Thanks assaqqaf any ideas for the underline not to go under the caret?